# Mongo Aggregation with nested array of Id´s

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm having a `Model` which is structured similar to this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5c878c5c18a4ff001b981zh5"),
  "books": [
    ObjectId("5d963a7544ec1b122ab2ddc"),
    ObjectId("5d963be01f663d168f8ea4dc"),
    ObjectId("5d963bcb1f663d168f8ea2f4"),
    ObjectId("5d963bdf1f663d16858ea7c9"),
}
```

Now I want to use the aggregation framework to get a list of only the populated books, like:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("5d963a7544ec1b122ab2ddc"), title: ...., ... },
 ..
```

Comment: Are the titles stored in another collection?

Comment: Yes. books are basically there own collection. The user Model above just stores some book ids, so I can populate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'books',
      let: { books: '$books' },
      pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { _id: { $in: ['_id', '$$books'] } } } }],
      as: 'bookInfos'
    }
  },
  { $unwind: '$bookInfos' },
  { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$bookInfos' } }
])
```

I am not too sure about your question, but I think this might be what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Somehow this query returns all the books existing in the database, instead of only the ones from the user collection. I could achieve the wanted results with this query though:

Answer (score 0):

So this query worked for me:

```
{
          $match: {
            _id: user._id,
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "books",
            localField: "books",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "booksInfo",
          },
        },
        { $unwind: "$booksInfo" },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$booksInfo",
          },
        },
```

Thanks @zishone. Somehow your query returned all the books available in the db and not only the ones from the User Model, but it works as desired when looking up the documents with local and foreignField.